# Auto indent doesn't work when using vim coding python

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I want to use vim to write python code but there is a problem on auto indention.
First I downloaded the latest python.vim from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790 and putted it in the correct dir.
Then I edited my vimrc.

```
syntax on
set nu
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
"set cindent
set autoindent
set smartindent
set expandtab
set filetype=python
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.pyw setf python
```

Now I find that keywords like 'for', 'if', 'while' can autoindent perfectly. But it doesn't work on 'def', 'try', 'except'.
What should I do? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have this line in my vimrc for long time, don't know if there is better way nowadays. but you could at least give it a try.

```
set cindent
autocmd FileType python setlocal foldmethod=indent smartindent shiftwidth=4 ts=4 et cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
```

and I have

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

too

Comment: When I add "filetype plugin indent on" to vimrc, I get auto-indentation correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That vim script you linked to doesn't do any auto-indentation, only syntax highlighting.

The auto-indentation you are observing is the one that's built into vim, it is designed for coding C, and it only recognizes the keywords described here:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cinwords%27

That's why it works for `if` and `while` but not `def` (there's no `def` in C). 
You turned it on with `set cindent`.

You may want to try another script like this one:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974

Comment: Actually when I add "filetype plugin indent on" to vimrc, I get auto-indentation correct. Does this mean the script I linked to has auto-indentation but I didn't turn it on?