# Properly indent after space in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to setup a smart indentation with vim. Basically I want the editor to tab after I enter. Here is an example

This is what it's doing currently after enter:

```
def method
|
end
```

this is what I want

```
def method
  |
end
```

This is strange because I have all of the obvious configurations in vimrc. Here is my .vimrc

```
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=2 smarttab
set number
set nowrap
set paste
set smartindent
set autoindent
set cindent
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570737/auto-indent-doesnt-work-when-using-vim-coding-python

Comment: I don't think you should use `set paste` except when you are actually pasting something.  Also I don't think you should be using all of `smartindent`, `autoindent`, and `cindent` together.

Comment: Try:  `set nocindent nopaste cinwords+=def smartindent`

Comment: Hey! that worked. Thanks Sergio